# Filtering matrices based on model

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

This should be quite easy for someone with linear-algebra skills, sorry if this sounds too basic :-)
I am looking for guidance to construct an efficient algorithm to filter a list of matrices based on the fitness to a certain model:
matrices are simple 3x2 discrete integer matrices (value range [0,4]), and the "model" is a matrix of this form as well.
e.g:

```
[1,2
 3,2
 1,4]
```

My goal is to find the matrix in the list which "looks the most" like the target model...
What would be an efficient way to accomplish this task, given that the list can contain more than hundreds of elements.
I have looked at simple solutions such as comparing the values, but this is not efficient at all.

Comment: Have you tried any matrix norms? Any vector norms (on the reshaped matrix)? By the way, should there be a 5 in the example if the value range was $[0,4]$?

Comment: I actually haven't tried yet, thanks for the tip, and for pointing out the typo :)

Comment: Let's look at a simpler problem, with $1\times2$ matrices, which we can interpret as points in the plane. So, you're given hundreds of points in the plane, and you want to know which one "looks the most like" some given point. I don't see how you can pssibly do that without calculating the distance from each point to the model point, and then finding the smallest of these distances. You might be able to save a little time by, say, sorting the points on the first coordinate, but you still have to do heaps of computation.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson I see the problem, so I need to find a good distance function to compare my 2 matrices...